# knockoutjs observablearray pubsub how to?

Tags: knockout.js, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to use pubsub messaging to notify viewmodel about changes made on observablearray.

viewModel1 have observableArray1
viewMOdel2 also uses observableArray2

I'm using  this to broadcast changes :

```
this.observableArray1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            this.observableArray1().push(newValue);
            pubsub.notifySubscribers(newValue, "observableArray1");
        },
            this);
```

and on other side:

```
postbox.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            this.observableArray1().(newValue);
        },
            this,
            "observableArray1");
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Gb (knockout-3.4.2.js:22)
    at Object.a.toJSON (knockout-3.4.2.js:56)
    at text (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-3.4.2.js:68), <anonymous>:3:67)
    at update (knockout-3.4.2.js:99)
    at function.a.B.i (knockout-3.4.2.js:73)
    at Function.Uc (knockout-3.4.2.js:52)
    at Function.Vc (knockout-3.4.2.js:51)
    at Function.U (knockout-3.4.2.js:51)
    at Function.ec (knockout-3.4.2.js:50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.observableArray1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            this.observableArray1().push(newValue);
            pubsub.notifySubscribers(newValue, "observableArray1");
        },
            this);
```

Adding newValue to the observableArray1 causes the subscribe to be called again which adds the value again which causes the subscribe to be called again creating an endless loop hence the circular structure error. There is no need to add the newValue to the observable array in the subscribe because it is already there.

```
this.observableArray1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            pubsub.notifySubscribers(newValue, "observableArray1");
        },
            this);
```